# How to host the OpenStreetMap Locally

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to host the OSM (OpenStreetMap) locally. I need the basic idea what are required for hosting the OSM and how the task can be done in a step wise manner. I have to host it in Windows7 environment.

Any kind of help will be useful.

Comment: What in detail do you mean by 'host'? Do you want to have the *whole* infrastructure that makes up OSM?

Answer (score 19):

[switch2osm](http://switch2osm.org/) contains detailed instructions and requirements for setting up a OSM server. If you have a Windows system then better set up a Linux VM inside it.

Answer (score 6):

*A bit too old but I will just put it here for someone who is searching for the same thing.*

An exact instance of OpenStreetMap can be hosted locally by following the [installation](https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/blob/master/INSTALL.md) guide of OpenStreetMap.

Quoting from the Link:

"These instructions are designed for setting up The Rails Port for development and testing. If you want to deploy the software for your own project, then see the notes at the end.

You can install the software directly on your machine, which is the traditional and probably best-supported approach. However, there is an alternative which may be easier: Vagrant. This installs the software into a virtual machine, which makes it easier to get a consistent development environment and may avoid installation difficulties. For Vagrant instructions, see VAGRANT.md.

These instructions are based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which is the platform used by the OSMF servers. The instructions also work, with only minor amendments, for all other current Ubuntu releases, Fedora and MacOSX

We don't recommend attempting to develop or deploy this software on Windows. If you need to use Windows, then try developing this software using Ubuntu in a virtual machine, or use Vagrant."

Comment: It is better to add the details here and reference the source than to redirect users to it.

Comment: There's a useful article on this for Ubuntu 18 and running your own map tile server with OSM data at [Linux Babe](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-18-04-osm)